# How can I uninstall a duplicate program?

Tags: 20.04, software-center, software-uninstall

Ubuntu Software center won’t allow me to view installed programs because automatic updates are paused – something I can’t change.

The command:

```
sudo apt remove cawbird
```

does not work.

I have two of these app icons in my app drawer and only one works.

Comment: What is cawbird? From where it was downloaded?

Comment: What is the output of `which cawbird`?

Comment: /usr/bin/cawbird    And last time I installed it due to it not working I did so with a deb package.

Comment: Then what is the output of `dpkg -S /usr/bin/cawbird` ?

Comment: cawbird: /usr/bin/cawbird

Answer (score 3):

You have to try removing it using [Snap](https://snapcraft.io/cawbird) and/or [Flatpak](https://flathub.org/apps/details/uk.co.ibboard.cawbird) by

```
snap remove cawbird
flatpak remove uk.co.ibboard.cawbird
```

For APT use

```
sudo apt-get autopurge cawbird
```

Comment: With the 1st command I get the error posted in comments below. With the 2nd I get: error: uk.co.ibboard.cawbird/*unspecified*/*unspecified* not installed

Answer (score 2):

`cawbird` is a snap

You can remove a snap by opening a terminal and typing:

`sudo snap remove <package>`

After completion, the folder for  will remain. You can check the name of the folder by navigating to `/home/snap`  and then you can remove it with:

`sudo snap rm -r <package_folder_name>`

[reference](https://linuxhint.com/remove-snap-package-ubuntu/)

Comment: error: cannot communicate with server: Post http://localhost/v2/snaps/cawbird: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: connection refused
+*When tried.*+